# How to track bounce back email and save it in database using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, smtp

I am working on a project where  i have to send email and also track the bounce back emails and store its information in the database table,Sending part is done and its working i used smtp  for sending emails  but now i have to track the bounce back emails i don't have any idea how to track bounce back emails using c#,so if anyone has worked on it or have any idea so kindly help me out any idea or any suggestion would be great.
here is my code for sending emails

```
 public string sendEmailToUser(string toAddress, string subject, string body)
    {
        try
        {

            MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
            mailMsg.To.Add(toAddress);
            mailMsg.From = new MailAddress("noreply@mushko.com", "No 
            Reply");
            mailMsg.Subject = subject;
            mailMsg.Body = body;
            mailMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;




            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new 
            NetworkCredential("noreply@mushko.com", "password");
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Send(mailMsg);
            return "success";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message.ToString();

        }

    }
```

Comment: you almost certainly dont get a bounce from sending - you need to read the failed delivery...

Comment: how to read the fail delivery, also i have to store it in the database  any code sample would be appreciable to get this done

Comment: read your inbox for failed delivery - they dont have a specific format but check for emails in it and pick em out

Comment: (Disclaimer - I work for Campaign Monitor) Bounce processing is reasonably complicated to get 100% correct. You may wish to consider using an ESP (mailgun, Campaign Monitor, MailChimp etc) to 'handle it for you'.